# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class data in D:\xampp\htdocs\Test1\tedboy\include\home\header.php on line 11

Tags: php

This code work before this. after i format my laptop, i cant use this code anymore. please help me to solve this. this is my final year project. Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class data in D:\xampp\htdocs\Test1\tedboy\include\home\header.php on line 11

```
?php include('db.php'); ?>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php //print_r($_SESSION['cart']); ?>
<?php date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'); ?>
<?php
    $jim = new data();
    $countproduct = $jim->countproduct();

    $cat = $jim->getcategory();

    class data {
        function countproduct(){
            $count = 0;
            $cart = isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? $_SESSION['cart']:array();
            foreach($cart as $row):
                if($row['qty']!=0){
                    $count = $count + 1;
                }
            endforeach;

            return $count;
        }
        function getcategory(){
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category");
            return $result;
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Tedboy Bakery</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/home/Tedboy.png" type="image" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap1.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main1.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/responsive1.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->       

</head><!--/head-->

<body>
<header id="header"><!--header-->

        <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Tedboy Bakery</title>
<link rel="icon" href="images/home/damailers_logo.png" type="image" />
<link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="category.php">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="cart.php">Cart <span class="badge"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>

        <li><a href="contact.php" >Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="border"></div>




  </div>

</body>
</html>


    </header><!--/header-->
```

Comment: Have you written `class data{` anywhere else other than shown here ?

Answer (score 0):

that's because you are using the class before defining it!
Move the Definition of the data class before this line:

```
$jim = new data();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should declare your data class before using it.

```
class data {  ...

$jim = new data();
```

Then, double check that your included files don't have the data class declaration already.